# How to apply Material Design to android versions < 5.0?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, backwards-compatibility, material-design

I given my application target as 21. So I can use the Material Design API's. But when I run the same on older devices whether I have to define different layout or theme or how it could me.

And also I have read the official document [Maintaining Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#SupportLib).
But still I was not clear to use the material theme on android devices less than 5 os.

And also where can I find the Android 5 related XML tags. And how the same tags applied when running on devices less than 5.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few library's to achieve the Material Design applicable to an earlier platforms less than API-21. 
An example of such library is this one:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1156. You can look on Android Arsenal for more library's like this.

Also this blog-post from Chris Banes is about Material Design on older platforms, I recommend that you read it: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/. I hope it will be helpful for reduce design complexity.